# On Windows, when is it necessary to append \ to a directory path for _stat to succeed?

Tags: c++, windows

I have tested _stat under VS2010 & VS2002:
the directory c:\system\ already exist in my PC.

```
struct _stat filestat;
unsigned int n1 = _stat("c:\\system",&filestat);
unsigned int n2 = _stat("c:\\",&filestat);
unsigned int n3 = _stat("c:\\system\\",&filestat);
unsigned int n4 = _stat("c:",&filestat);
```

Result:

```
n1=0;
n2=0;
n3=0xffffffff;
n4=0xffffffff;
```

Can any one know why and when i need to put "\" in the directory path?

Comment: C: is a drive, not a folder.  No clue why you get an error over c:\system\

Comment: @user4581301 Shouldn't stat-ing C: be exactly the same as stat-ing C:\ ? (I admit to not having tried this in many years.)

Comment: @zwol: `C:`, at least in some contexts, means "Use the cached working directory on the C: drive", not "The root of the C: drive". That is, in DOS, if you do: `C:`, `cd \Windows`, `D:`, `dir C:`, you get a listing of the `C:\Windows` directory, not `C:\ `, because each drive has a memory of its working directory (it's not just one working directory across all drives), and `C:` is remembering `\Windows`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I thought that only applied to programs running inside CMD.EXE "console" windows, being a DOS backward compatibility thing.  I suppose OP could be doing that.

Comment: @zwol: Mostly, but it seems like [some APIs still use it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101011-00/?p=12563). Read the comments at that link; apparently in some cases, the WinAPI function doesn't play with the per-drive setting, while the CRT (POSIX-like) function does. So `_stat` (CRT) might use the per-drive working directory; you'd have to test.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I think *none* of those `stat` calls should have failed (assuming, as you say, that the `c:\system` directory does exist).

Please run the following test program and edit its output into your question:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

static void test_stat(const char *path)
{
    struct _stat st;
    if (_stat(path, &st))
        printf("%s: %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
    else
        printf("%s: success, mode=%x\n", path, st.st_mode);
}

int main(void)
{
    test_stat("c:");
    test_stat("c:\\");
    test_stat("c:\\system");
    test_stat("c:\\system\\");
    return 0;
}
```

(If you didn't realize that you can edit your question, look immediately under the blue "c++" tag for a row of tiny grey words.  Those are buttons.  One of them should be "edit".)

Comment: Kinda forgot I could do that to questions. Fixed.  `_stat` the function must be paired with `_stat` the structure or Visual studio macro madness ensues.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks.